# DCOM errors in server log

Tags: windows-sbs, dcom

I am running SBS 2011 SP1 server and I would like to fix repeating error from event viewer:

> An error event occurred.  EventID: 0xC0002719 Time Generated:
>   05/11/2017   13:01:11 Event String: DCOM was unable to communicate
>   with the computer PC123.contoso.com using any of the configured
>   protocols.

The error appears every 30 minutes for all AD computers.

I am able to ping PC123.contoso.com from server. FQDN is correctly translated to corresponding IP address. The station can ping server and access shared resources.

I have found some article regarding default firewall block on stations so I have created GPO for the server to allow inbound file and printer sharing, remote administration exception and remote desktop exception. Unfortunately with no luck. Firewall on the server is disabled at all.

We have only one server for everything. No other DC or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Every 30 minutes the Windows SBS Manager service attempts to connect to all domain-joined workstations and servers to collect information used to populate the Windows Small Business Server Console and its network reports. For example, because of this process the SBS console can show which computers are currently online, have updated anti-virus/anti-malware definitions, are low on disk space, etc.:

[image]

When a workstation isn't accessible event ID 10009 is logged in the System event log. This usually happens because the computer is offline (e.g. off or out of the office). It can also happen if the target computer's firewall is blocking communication. Because the domain group policies that apply to computers in an SBS-based domain open the required ports for this communication, this problem only happens on systems where the Windows firewall rules have been modified, or a 3rd-party firewall is installed that does not integrate with Group Policy.

The MSDN article [How to troubleshoot DCOM 10009 error logged in system event?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2010/03/15/how-to-troubleshoot-dcom-10009-error-logged-in-system-event/) describes how to troubleshoot this error when it's not caused by the remote computer being offline:

1. Ping <remote server> & IP Address of remote server to make sure network traffic is fine.
2. Telnet <remote server> 135 to make sure the Port 135 is not blocked by firewall.
3. If we have configured dynamic port for RPC communication, we can check what status the port resources are  on both servers using  below command:

   ```
   netstat –anb
   ```

   If all dynamic ports are used, or only a few are left, you can consider [expanding the dynamic port range](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=154596). See also [DCOM port range configuration problems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/217351/en-us).
4. If all above tests are fine, we can use DTCPing tool to verify if the DCOM communication between two servers is fine. See [How to troubleshoot connectivity issues in MS DTC by using the DTCPing tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918331/en-us).

   **Note:** The DTCPing tool is not specific for troubleshooting MSDTC issues; it can be used to troubleshooting all DCOM communication issues.

In any case, in most SBS environments this error can be ignored as long as the SBS Console is showing updated information for all of the domain computers.

Answer (score -1):

Reference steps mentioned in blog - **How to troubleshoot DCOM 10009 error logged in system event**:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2010/03/15/how-to-troubleshoot-dcom-10009-error-logged-in-system-event/

Comment: On this Q&A site we value answers that stand on their own. Hyperlinks alone point toward an answer [without actually being one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). Please [edit] your answer so that it includes the essential elements from your linked source.